# How to import csv file into MySQL with php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to import csv into MySQL using php?

I have an `ImportData.php` file containing the following code which doesn't produce an error message.  The `ImportData.php` and `abc.csv` are in the same folder on a web server while MySQL is on another server.

If `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` will not work, what other ways are there to import with php? I want to set a cronjob with that task.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Comment: `LOCAL INFILE` and _another server_ is, if the file is on your maschine, not working

Comment: OK @Olaf Dietsche does have made the better point :) configuration!

Comment: "does not work" is neither an error message nor a meaningful diagnosis. What error does it emit?

Answer (score 1):

Related to your question, we're happy to have a few paths to resolve it:

**1. LOAD DATA INFILE**

A great MySQL feature that allows you to import a CSV file directly, in a single query.

The SQL command you're looking for is LOAD DATA INFILE

Manual page here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Quick example:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'fileName'
     INTO TABLE tableName
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    @variable1,
    @variable2,
    etc
    )        
    set
    (
    field4 = concat(@variable1,@variable2)
    );
```

That's a fairly basic example, but it covers most of what you'd want. The manual page gives full details of how to do some very complex stuff with it.

**2. Parsing your CSV and inserting it programatically **

```
    set_time_limit(10000);


    $con = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);} 


    $fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");

    while( !feof($fp) ) {
      if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ';', '"')) {
         continue;
      }

        $importSQL = "INSERT INTO table_name                VALUES('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."')";

        $qry = $con->query(($importSQL) ;

        if($qry === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->error, E_USER_ ERROR);
     }  

    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would advise against what you are actually proposing. The mysql_* extension is [presently deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), one should never write new code with it. moreover, OP obviously know about LOAD DATA INFILE, they actually use a specific keyword to execute a specific need. Your solution actually makes it worse by preventing this specific need to be met.

Answer (score 0):

See the MySQL manual about this [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/load-data.html)

> The LOCAL keyword affects expected location of the file and error handling, as described later. LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work. See Section 7.1.6, “[Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/load-data-local.html)”.

So you must first check your MySQL configuration, if it is allowed.

---

The alternative could be to parse the CSV file yourself, and import it line by line with an `INSERT INTO` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I got it to work by following your code to parse the CSV and inserting it programatically.  Is there a way not to import the 1st line because it is field header?

Thank you so much.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.